# User with low reputation converted all answers to Community Wiki. Bug?

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

Take a look at [Failed to allocate memory: 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8/13813122#13813122)

I posted an answer. A few months later, a user by name the of [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062658/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) with reputation of 29 converted my answer (and all other answers for the same question) to a community wiki.

As a result, I lost a boatload of reputation (the answer has been upvoted 21 times).

Why does such a low-reputation user have the right to convert answers en-mass to a Community Wiki? Isn't permission limited to the author of the original post?

Comment: The answers there read like a classic forum.

Comment: I thought you keep all the rep from an answer from before when it becomes CW. Right? It's not suppose to nullify *all* upvotes, IIRC

Comment: @MichaelT Agreed. More than half the answers there should probably be nuked and the question un-wikied.

Comment: @Mysticial The fact that there are so many possible solutions suggests to me that the error message is vague and thus not descriptive of the real problem, and that the question should be closed.

Comment: @animuson That's certainly another option. (I don't have an opinion on whether it *should* be closed.) But at the very least, it will stop the flow of forum-like answers that keep pouring in.

Comment: @animuson Like half of them are people saying the same thing: change the ram limit.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, we need the ability to flag answers as duplicates of other answers and have the UI group them all in one section.

Comment: @Bill I've tried flagging answers that say the same thing, but they're declined because we should "just downvote". Feel free to propose that. I'll upvote it.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203018/142724

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That user posted the 31st answer. When a question goes over 30 answers, all the answers and the question become community wiki.

Since user [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062658/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) is the one who put the final nail in the coffin, he becomes "responsible" for converting everything to wki.

Comment: True, but there's still a bug. Normally it should say "Post Made Community Wiki by question having more than 30 answers", see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/revisions?page=2) for example. It says that for both the question and all answers.

Comment: Quite hilarious side effect given the user name.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah. I remember when they started showing the user instead of that general message. They should probably change it so something like "Post Made Community Wiki by user XX posting the 31st answer."

Comment: "aaaaaaaaaaa" was the sound heard when everyone's answers turned CW.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've brought that up before somewhere. It's that if you delete answers and it drops back below 30, the system forgets that reason and goes with the user. They said it's determined on-the-fly so it only shows if it *currently* has 30 [undeleted] answers.

Comment: Adjunct question: How can I find all non-CW questions that currently have 30 undeleted answers?

Comment: @AlEverett The [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) can probably do it.

Comment: I wasn't being serious. That is, I've no plans to go on a "post the 31st answer" binge.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can post multiple answers per question.  You can go post 30 answers to one question to CW it.  You'll almost certainly end up flagged, suspended, and have the question un-CWed though.

Comment: But as @doorknob said above, shouldn't users keep the rep they earned before the post became CW?

Comment: @AdamRackis They do keep it. The OP probably didn't know that though.

Comment: @Mysticial - ahh.  The original question implied to me that the post was made CW this morning, and he lost a bunch of rep.  I can now see the post was made CW way back in July.

Comment: It's time to lower Jon Skeet's rep down to 0, who's with me??

Comment: @ScottW You can't. Wiki'ed posts keep the rep from before they went wiki. Deleting a post when it has a score of 3+ also keeps the rep. So you can't just close and delete all the questions he's ever answered.

Comment: But... what you *can* do is red-flag all his posts. That's -100 each. 27k * 100 = 2.7 million. That will reduce him to 1. :)

Comment: @animuson cool, this does explain this. No bug then! Mysti - we're talking about Jon Skeet. *Jon Skeet*. **Jon Skeet**. Even if every single user with enough rep will use all his spam flags on *The Skeet*, he's still have infinite amount of reputation. :)

Comment: @AdamRackis The "lost a bunch of rep" was likely "upvotes on the answer since when it was made CW gave no rep" - rep wasn't *taken away* but rather *never granted*.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not exactly correct :) Jon Skeet doesn't *have* reputation, he *generates* it. You can't zero his reputation - it's a physical paradox: if Jon Skeet's rep could be made zero all reputation in the world would be annihilated in the process! :)

Comment: @Gili But there are 13 deleted answers out of a total of 35. Some of which had been deleted after you brought attention to it with this meta post. The user in question had in fact posted the 31st (undeleted) answer *at the time*.

Comment: On second glance, you are right. This makes sense now (though the message is definitely misleading).